# Unable to install anaconda on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: anaconda

During anaconda installation on  ubuntu 18.04, it stops and the following error is displayed:

> *line 380 :/home/shrinidhi /anaconda3/pkgs/ python-3.7.0-hc3d631a_0 :no such file or directory exists*

Comment: What steps did you follow before this error occurred?

Comment: Downloaded the .sh file from the anaconda website then executed the bash command along with the path of the .sh file downloaded

Comment: i followed the same steps as given in anaconda website to install it on linux system.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the `.sh` file in `Downloads`, try

```
bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-5.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

for 64-Bit PCs.
But if you did not installed the `.sh` file in Downloads, replace `~/Downloads/` with the place where you installed it.